# d3 multi-series chart zoom - pivoted json

Tags: d3.js

I've a multi series line chart which I'd like to have it zoom/pan operations. Zoom/Pan is working but it only zooms or moves one of the lines not all of them. Can you help me to figure out the problem? JSFiddle is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/scusyxx/b2GsZ/6/

I think the problem is in zoom function

```
zoomed = function () {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select("path.line")
       .attr("d", function (d) {
           return line(d.data);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is. As I suspected, the zoom piece should look like below. Instead of svg.select, I should have written svg.selectAll.

```
zoomed = function () {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll("path.line")
       .attr("d", function (d) {
           return line(d.data);
        })
}
```